# How can I deploy a NeoMAD application and debug it on an iPhone device?

Tags: ios, iphone, deployment, mobile-application, neomad

I am compiling my application with NeoMAD for an iOS target. I was able to run it on the emulator, but how can I deploy it and debug it on an iPhone device?

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not clear. I edited it, I hope it is clearer now. There is no specific part of the code that is failing. I just wanted to know how to deploy the application on an actual device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deploy applications on an iOS device, you must go through the following steps:

- enroll to the iOS Developer Program
- obtain a development certificate
- declare the device you will use for tests
- create an App ID for your application
- create a development provisioning profile and install it on your device

If there are several developers in your organization, you only need to enroll once. The enrolled person will be the administrator of your team in the Developer Program and he/she will be able to invite other developers to join the team (they will have to register as Apple Developers).

Note that this is not related to the fact that you are using NeoMAD to build your application. You will have to go through this process too if you create your iOS application using XCode directly.